# Controlling more relays than the no. of free IO pins a uC has - Low-cost options

Tags: relay, multiplexer, gpio, expander

While I understand that moving up to a high pin-count uC might be the simplest option, I am looking for Low-cost options to do the same with low pin-count uC.

Would like to control a maximum of 8 relays, using an ATtiny85, which has 5 available GPIO pins, of which I definitely need to set aside 2 for some other purpose, leaving me 3. One obvious approach that comes to my mind is a Mux. Given 3 pins, 2^3 = 8, fits nicely. However I was wondering if the relays (which control the power-supply socket for servers), would de-energise, while changing mux values ?

Are there other gotchas with this approach ? Are there any alternative methods available ? I've heard about IO expanders, but would it be a worthwhile approach from complexity / cost standpoint ?

Comment: In order not to make relays to de energise , use a latch at the ouput of the mux , the latch will keep the logic(1) while switching between MUX pins :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [TPIC6C595](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpic6c595.pdf) is a power version of the 74HC595 **shift register**, serial in parallel out, with 8 output channels, each capable of driving 100mA. You only need three pins: serial data, serial clock and latch, and if needed you can cascade multiple devices for more than 8 outputs.

It contains clamping diodes to protect against the relays' inductive voltage.

Comment: As an added bonus, this device is far more likely than the others to be capable of driving the relays directly without an external transistor.  As [noted by mjh2007](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/26348/857), most other solutions will need another transistor.  This will, of course, still need a diode to protect against damage from the inductance of the relay coil.

Comment: "The device contains a built-in voltage clamp on the outputs for inductive transient protection."

Comment: Thanks @stevenvh. This device seems ideal, and also the current cost seems to be nice. Just what I needed. +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 7):

There are many I/O Expanders out there that use either SPI or I2C buses. With a single MSSP module you can control almost an infinite amount of digital outputs like LEDs or Relays.

See the Microchip datasheets or application notes for the following parts:
SPI - [MCP23S08](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en021817)
I2C - [MCP23008](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en021393)

NOTE: These parts by themselves will not sink/source enough current to activate a relay, however adding a transistor at the output pin will allow you to drive a relay.

Answer (score 2):

A mux won't work, because you need to latch/disable the output using another one of your pins, and have an input state for on/off of the relay you are muxed through to, using another pin. An SPI IO expander would seem better, but then you need an SPI library on your chip.

Comment: Yes, indeed a mux alone won't work, my bad.